# Any common errors on psycopg2 importing?

Tags: python

So I am inserting into PostgreSQL 9.2 with `psycopg2` and I am on Python 2.7. I use `try: except:` on this insert and it doesn't give me any errors and runs through like all is well. Same with connecting to the database.

Any common errors that everyone runs into when using this that I'm not thinking of?

The problem is that the `insert` doesn't actually insert. It doesn't give errors but it doesn't import anything either

```
cur.execute("""
INSERT INTO data ( date, time, name, qty, dayornight, bl, idc, prices, contractlength)
VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);""",
    (datet, timet, "lod", qty, "day", btores, 0, prices, contracts))
```

Thanks guys! Like I said, literally no errors and everything runs great. I checked *psycopg2* and it doesn't have anything in the FAQ.

Comment: Is there a problem you have, or are you just wondering if something could go wrong eventually somehow ?

Comment: wow dur, I edited. It just isn't importing anything, just like the code was never there

Comment: It's not in the FAQ because it's in the first example of the first page of the manual. Nobody had ever asked before. `commit()`.

Answer (score 0):

By default the *psycopg2* connection's [autocommit](http://packages.python.org/psycopg2/connection.html#connection.autocommit) attribute value is `False` (manual commit) as per DBAPI specification in *psycopg2* and therefore *"a new transaction is started at the first command execution: the methods* `commit()` *or* `rollback()` *must be manually invoked to terminate the transaction"*.

So, for your `insert` to be committed you'll need after it (assuming that `cur` is a cursor, you just need to call commit on the cursor's connection):

```
cur.connection.commit()
```

Alternatively you can set the connections `autocommit` attribute value to `True` and then *"no transaction is handled by the driver and every statement sent to the backend has immediate effect"*.